# How do you manage data in the Fluid Framework?

Tags: javascript, fluid-framework

The documentation says the following:

> The Fluid container defines the application logic while containing persistent data.

I have a few questions to understand better understand the data management.

1. Is the amount of data that can be stored in a container limited by the available storage of the machine or server the fluid app is running in?
2. How long is the data persisted for?
3. Can data in the container be moved to external data storage solutions?
4. For production, is a database needed for Fluid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some good questions that the Fluid Framework documentation does not answer well (yet.)

#### Is the amounted of data that can be stored in a container limited by the available storage of the [client] machine or server [machine] that the Fluid app is running on?

Generally, the client is the limit, **but** the amount of data that can be stored in a container should not be capped at the memory of the client machine. Each [Data Object](https://fluidframework.com/apis/aqueduct/dataobject/) within the container can be virtualized, so only the first Data Object *must* be loaded. However, the fluidframework currently has a solvable inefficiency where the client that [Summarizes](https://fluidframework.com/docs/advanced/summarizer/) the state must load all of the container data locally. This could be avoided by distributing the summary or by not summarizing parts that haven't changed. We're well set up for both in large part because the summary is usually stored in git and therefore is content addressable.

You *could* manufacture a scenario where the server is the limit, but it would be very contrived.

#### How long is the data persisted for?

Data is persisted indefinitely. Our reference implementation keeps data infinitely. If you self-host, you can manage the data life cycle, like orderer storage duration and summary storage duration. A managed offering would include life cycle mechanisms.

#### Can data in the container be moved to external data storage solutions?

Yes, but not with a server to server hook. Data would be moved using a non-human client that connects to the document and writes the data out. This is an interesting area of work.

#### For production, is a database needed for Fluid?

If you self host the service, you'll need to provision a blob storage for old operations (e.g. mongodb), an orderer for current ops(e.g. kafka), and a git storage for summaries (could live in the blob storage). These are just the parts of the fluid service. The repository has helm charts & docker compose files for these requirements.